# R Markdown is not working after my first attempt on R Shiny

Tags: r, error-handling, shiny, r-markdown

Yesterday I wanted to write an Interactive R document and started using R-Shiny. As soon as I hit knit, I got an error something like this...

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rmarkdown’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> namespace ‘xfun’ 0.17 is already loaded, but >= 0.21 is required

Then I tried many things to fix it using google and finally updated some of my packages. But it didn't work.

So I wanna give it up today and want to write a normal markdown. No matter what I write in the Markdown I'm getting the same output shown below.

> [1] 127
> Warning message:
> In system(paste0("rmarkdown::render '", input, "'")) :
> 'rmarkdown::render' not found

Finally, I uninstalled R Studio and reinstalled it. But no change. Can anyone help me?

Here are some technical details about my R Studio

```
version 
                     
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.2                         
year           2020                        
month          06                          
day            22                          
svn rev        78730                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
nickname       Taking Off Again         

str(allPackage <- installed.packages(.Library, priority = "high"))

chr [1:29, 1:16] "base" "boot" "class" "cluster" "codetools" "compiler" "datasets" "foreign" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:29] "base" "boot" "class" "cluster" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:16] "Package" "LibPath" "Version" "Priority" ...


allPackage [, c(1,3:5)]

           Package      Version    Priority      Depends                                          
base       "base"       "4.0.2"    "base"        NA                                               
boot       "boot"       "1.3-25"   "recommended" "R (>= 3.0.0), graphics, stats"                  
class      "class"      "7.3-18"   "recommended" "R (>= 3.0.0), stats, utils"                     
cluster    "cluster"    "2.1.2"    "recommended" "R (>= 3.4.0)"                                   
codetools  "codetools"  "0.2-18"   "recommended" "R (>= 2.1)"                                     
compiler   "compiler"   "4.0.2"    "base"        NA                                               
datasets   "datasets"   "4.0.2"    "base"        NA                                               
foreign    "foreign"    "0.8-81"   "recommended" "R (>= 4.0.0)"                                   
graphics   "graphics"   "4.0.2"    "base"        NA                                               
grDevices  "grDevices"  "4.0.2"    "base"        NA                                               
grid       "grid"       "4.0.2"    "base"        NA                                               
KernSmooth "KernSmooth" "2.23-18"  "recommended" "R (>= 2.5.0), stats"                            
lattice    "lattice"    "0.20-44"  "recommended" "R (>= 3.0.0)"                                   
MASS       "MASS"       "7.3-53.1" "recommended" "R (>= 3.1.0), grDevices, graphics, stats, utils"
Matrix     "Matrix"     "1.2-18"   "recommended" "R (>= 3.2.0)"                                   
methods    "methods"    "4.0.2"    "base"        NA                                               
mgcv       "mgcv"       "1.8-35"   "recommended" "R (>= 3.6.0), nlme (>= 3.1-64)"                 
nlme       "nlme"       "3.1-152"  "recommended" "R (>= 3.4.0)"                                   
nnet       "nnet"       "7.3-15"   "recommended" "R (>= 3.0.0), stats, utils"                     
parallel   "parallel"   "4.0.2"    "base"        NA                                               
rpart      "rpart"      "4.1-15"   "recommended" "R (>= 2.15.0), graphics, stats, grDevices"      
spatial    "spatial"    "7.3-12"   "recommended" "R (>= 3.0.0), graphics, stats, utils"           
splines    "splines"    "4.0.2"    "base"        NA                                               
stats      "stats"      "4.0.2"    "base"        NA                                               
stats4     "stats4"     "4.0.2"    "base"        NA                                               
survival   "survival"   "3.1-12"   "recommended" "R (>= 3.4.0)"                                   
tcltk      "tcltk"      "4.0.2"    "base"        NA                                               
tools      "tools"      "4.0.2"    "base"        NA                                               
utils      "utils"      "4.0.2"    "base"        NA
```

Comment: What is that: `system(paste0("rmarkdown::render '", input, "'"))`? Is it you who typed this code?

Comment: RE: first error message, as suggested you need to update the xfun package. Regarding the second error message, that line of code `system(paste0("rmarkdown::render '", input, "'"))` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Please provide more clarity as to what you were attempting. Were you looking to build a shiny app with a rmarkdown document using flexdashboard? Were you looking to create an app that provides a PDF output of a parameterized r-markdown document?

Comment: You don't knit shiny apps, unless you are rendering Rmarkdown document that includes shiny functionality. Please give a reprex of your Rmarkdown code. what about running `install.packages("rmarkdown", dep = TRUE)`. What libraries are you loading?

Comment: No, I didn't type in anything. It was the output when I run the rmd file.

Comment: Yes, @Phil... Actually, my main aim is to create some interactivity in my md files(such as some widgets). What I'm trying to do is writing an interactive document in Rmd and then render it to a markdown(md). Also, this was my first attempt to shiny and I'm a little confused.

Comment: I would suggest you go through this book: https://mastering-shiny.org/